# Google Chrome opens two tabs when opened

Tags: google-chrome

When I open Chrome it opens two tabs (both the home screen) instead of just one.

How do I reduce this to one tab?

I am using Ubuntu 12.04

Answer (score 8):

Type this on the address bar `chrome://settings` & enter where chrome will take you to the settings panel. Fine **On start-up** & select **Open a specific page or set of pages**, then click **set pages** link. There you can remove the extra tab from there. See below image for reference.

[image]

Comment: This often happens when you have a duplicate "www.google.com". This can happen when you "sync" chrome with your Gmail account.

Answer (score 3):

Go to Settings -> On startup section -> Open a specific page or set of pages and hit "Set pages".

Remove the one you do not need.

Answer (score 0):

In settings at the bottom click on **Show Advanced Settings** then at the bottom again click on **Reset Web Settings** After you are finished you'll have to enable your extentions and reset your start pages.

Terry